# How to trigger Mono execution after another Mono terminates

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have a problem when I try to execute a Mono inside `doFinally` clause.
This is my code.

```
public interface Locks {

    Mono<ReactiveDistributedLock> doLock(LockParams params);

    Mono<Boolean> doUnlock(ReactiveDistributedLock lock);

    default <T> Mono<T> withLock(LockParams params, Supplier<Mono<T>> stage) {
        return doLock(params)
                .flatMap(lock -> stage.get().doFinally(ignored -> doUnlock(lock)));
}
```

The problem is that `doUnlock(lock)` inside `doFinally()` returns a mono that no one is subscribed for because `doFinally` is not chaining. So the async code part in `doUnlock` is never actually executed.

Is there any way to avoid this using `Mono` or `Flux` helpers?

Comment: hey @koguro, we are working on an operator that might help with your issue. If you have time to play with the preview and provide feedback: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/pull/1221

Comment: hi @SimonBaslé. Yes, this is looking very promising! Should I try and use reactor-core 3.2.0-SNAPSHOT for this?

Comment: hey @koguro that feature has now been merged into master and available in plain 3.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT. it is now called `usingWhen` and is obtaining the resource reactively from a `Publisher<R>` as well

Comment: @SimonBaslé it's definitely working and definitely looking better than the variant from the answer here but API is a little confusing and inconsistent. `Mono.usingWhen()` and `Flux.usingWhen()` have different sets of overrides (Flux has one convenient with only asyncCleanup callback and Mono has an extra one with asyncCancel). Plus some typos in Javadoc :) But overall its cool. Thanks for your work :)
P.S. I've used 3.2.0.M2 version

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Use `Mono#then.`

Unfortunately, you cannot avoid the usage of Mono/Flux, once your API is built on top of it, however, you may HACK that problem in the following way.

To chain several independent executions which should be subscribed one after the other and the result of the first will be returned after the first has been finished, there is a `Mono#then` operator which allows writing following (promise-like) code:

```
public interface Locks {

    Mono<ReactiveDistributedLock> doLock(LockParams params);

    Mono<Boolean> doUnlock(ReactiveDistributedLock lock);

    default <T> Mono<T> withLock(LockParams params, Supplier<Mono<T>> stage) {
        return doLock(params)
                .flatMap(lock -> 
                    stage.get()
                         .flatMap(value -> 
                            doUnlock(lock)
                            .then(Mono.just(value))
                         )
                );
    }
}
```

Here, to chain execution and then release the lock and then return staged value, we use `flatMap` to map value as the releasing of the lock and `then` returning of the staged value again. (admit, sounds awkward)

**Note**, in the case of *error* terminal signal, `then` will be ignored. Thus, to achieve ***try-finally*** behaviors, it might be required providing additional `orErrorResume` operator, as depicted in the following example:

```
public interface Locks {

    Mono<ReactiveDistributedLock> doLock(LockParams params);

    Mono<Boolean> doUnlock(ReactiveDistributedLock lock);

    default <T> Mono<T> withLock(LockParams params, Supplier<Mono<T>> stage) {
        return doLock(params)
                .flatMap(lock -> 
                    stage.get()
                         .flatMap(value -> 
                            doUnlock(lock)
                            .then(Mono.just(value))
                         )
                         .onErrorResume(t -> 
                            doUnlock(lock)
                            .then(Mono.error(t))
                         )
                );
    }
}
```

Comment: The second example does not work because there is no `lock` in `onErrorResume`. Should be like this 

    doLock(params)
                .flatMap(lock ->
                        stage.get()
                                .flatMap(result ->
                                        doUnlock(lock)
                                                .then(Mono.just(result)))
                                .onErrorResume(error ->
                                        doUnlock(lock)
                                                .then(Mono.error(error)))
                );

Comment: @Oleh Dokuka can you please share few steps inside doLock() method thanks